# Looping backwards starting with a found value

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

Suppose I have a `map<int, set<int>>` called `my_map` and I want to start at the element with key value `5` and loop *backward* until I get to the beginning, and check each set for a certain criterion. (I need to go backward, because I want to `break` if the criterion is met.)

`std::find` returns a forward iterator, so the way I thought of to do it is

```
for (auto rit = std::make_reverse_iterator(++my_map.find(A[i])); rit != my_map.rend(); ++rit) { 
//check conditions on rit->second
}
```

Is that the best way?

Comment: `map::find` returns a bidrectional iterator not a forward iterator. That will do what you want.

Comment: `std::find` returns the same type as you call it with. Since `std::map` traffics in bidirectional iterators, calling `std::find` on the range managed by a map will return a bidirectional iterator. The code in the question, though, doesn’t use `std::find`. It uses `map::find`, which also returns a bidirectional iterator.

Comment: Looks to me like your map is called `indices`, not `my_map`. <g>

Comment: @John Whoops! That's right, it's bidirectional. I'm still learning here, so does that mean I don't have to call make_reverse_iterator? What should I do instead?

Comment: You don't have to do anything instead, just use the iterator returned by `find`, use `--` to go backwards.

Comment: @John As for the boolean condition in the loop, is it preferred to say rit >= my_map.begin()? Or some other workaround to get the first element? (Making it rit != my_map.begin() will miss the first element)

Comment: `>=` doesn't work for bidrectional iterators. You need `rit != my_map.begin()` but test it at the end of your loop (after you've checked for the condition not before). Something like `for (auto i = map.find(); ; --i) { ...; if (i == map.begin()) break; }`